# Caliburn Micro dialog window's width/height is being arbitrarily set

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

Bizzare problem that I found while working with Caliburn micro's window manager.

I have the following code which shows a dialog window

```
sendLogicDialogViewModel.Initialize(CompiledCodeList);
dynamic settings = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
settings.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

windowManager.ShowDialog(sendLogicDialogViewModel, null, settings);
```

Which works perfectly.. but for some reason it's screwing around with the view's declaration of window height in XAML. I've made a very simple view to demonstrate my point:

```
<Window x:Class="DDCLogicInstaller.SendLogicDialogView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        cal:Bind.Model="DDCLogicInstaller.SendLogicDialogViewModel"
        >
    <Button Content="300" Height="100" Width="100"/>
</Window>
```

This is what I expect to see in the dialog window (This is what it shows in design view of Visual Studio)

[image]

But instead, this is what I get:

[image]

What gives? Why is it setting the height/width of the dialog window arbitrarily? Is there some setting that I have to touch in windowManager? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight`" to your root `Window` element in your `SendLogicDialogView`, or pass it as another setting.

This behaviour isn't specific to Caliburn.Micro, it is the standard WPF behaviour when a `Width` and `Height` aren't specified on the `Window` and the `SizeToContent` is set to `Manual` (the default), the window will have a default width and height.

Comment: Really? That's pretty weird, when I tried to use the regular show method on the window without the window manager, I didn't have the same problem. Anyhow this fixes the issue. Thanks.